# Trying to call another batch file in a for loop, get "The system cannot find the path specified" error

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to debug my code below for hours, but still couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code below. I'm getting "The system cannot find the path specified" error. Appreciate some advice on this. Thanks.

```
 @echo off &setlocal
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "D:\*.bat"') do (
        for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("sample.csv") do (
            set "search=profile"
            set "replace=profile-%%a"
            set "textfile=login.txt"
            set "newfile=login-%%a.txt"
            call Repl.bat "%search%" "%replace%" L < "%textfile%" > "%newfile%"     
            echo %%a %%b !search! !replace!
            )
    )
```

Comment: Standard `delayed expansion` error - thousands of articles on SO - it #1 FAQ. Please use the `search` facility to locate cures. You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display or use the run-time value of any variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block"). This apples to `textfile` and `newfile` which do not exist until the code-block is run, by which time they have been replaced by their values at the start of the code-block, ie. *nothing*

Comment: In the line `call Repl.bat ...` replace all `%` with `!`

Comment: or skip all those `set` commands and `call Repl.bat "profile" "profile-%%a" L < "login.txt" > "login-%%a.txt"`

Comment: What is the purpose of `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "D:\*.bat"') do …` when you don't use `%%i` anywhere within the loop? Additionally, why are you asking for `tokens 1-4` when you're only using `%%a` and `%%b`, i.e. `tokens=1-2`?

Comment: Repl.bat was deprecated many years ago already. You should consider using the newer version [JREPL](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

Comment: Remove the first `setlocal`, one is enough...

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I realize what I did wrong on my code now. Appreciate the guidance and help.

Answer (score 0):

You've already utilised the required delayed expansion, in the line beneath your batch file call:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-2 Delims=," %%A In ("sample.csv") Do (Set "search=profile"
    Set "replace=profile-%%A"
    Set "textfile=login.txt"
    Set "newfile=login-%%A.txt"
    Call "Repl.bat" "!search!" "!replace!" L<"!textfile!">"!newfile!"
    Echo %%A %%B !search! !replace!)
Pause
```

However, as you're already using `Call` you may be able to just double the percent characters:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-2 Delims=," %%A In ("sample.csv") Do (Set "search=profile"
    Set "replace=profile-%%A"
    Set "textfile=login.txt"
    Set "newfile=login-%%A.txt"
    Call "Repl.bat" "%%search%%" "%%replace%%" L<"%%textfile%%">"%%newfile%%"
    Echo %%A %%B !search! !replace!)
Pause
```

You could of course decide not to set variables unnecessarily, removing the reliance on delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-2 Delims=," %%A In ("sample.csv") Do (
    Call "Repl.bat" "profile" "profile-%%A" L<"login.txt">"login-%%A.txt"
    Echo %%A %%B profile profile-%%A)
Pause
```

Or pre-set them so that you can manage them easier, not set them within the loop and remove the delayed expansion reliance:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "search=profile"
Set "replace=profile-%%A"
Set "textfile=login.txt"
Set "newfile=login-%%A.txt"
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-2 Delims=," %%A In ("sample.csv") Do (
    Call "Repl.bat" "%search%" "%replace%" L<"%textfile%">"%newfile%"
    Echo %%A %%B %search% %replace%)
Pause
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the detailed explanation, Compo. Really really appreciate it. I got the code working now.

Comment: @Dax, I'm glad you've got it working. Please consider marking the answer as accepted, by clicking on the large grey check mark to its upper left; thank you.